# Ruby XPath to find Attribute

Tags: ruby, xpath

What Ruby library can be used to select **attribute** using XPath, and to use it as the starting point for other XPath queries.

Example:

```
<root>
  <add key="A" value="B" />
  <add key="C" value="D" />
  <add foo="E" bar="F" />
</root>
```

Desired code:

```
get_pair "//*/@key", "../@value"
get_pair "//*/@foo", "../@bar"
```

Expected output:

```
"A" "B"
"C" "D"
"E" "F"
```

Pseudo implementation:

```
def get_pair(key, value)
  xml_doc.select[key].each do |a|
    puts [a, a.select[value]]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your starting point would be [REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/)

The "challenge" here is how to treat an attribute node as a child node, and this can be done by using [singleton methods](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/singletonmethods.html), then everything else follows naturally:

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML  # so that we don't have to prefix everything with REXML::...

def get_pair(xml_doc, key, value)
  XPath.each(xml_doc, key) do |node| 
    if node.is_a?(Attribute)
      def node.parent
        self.element
      end
    end
    puts "\"#{node}\" \"#{XPath.first(node, value)}\""
  end
end

xml_doc = Document.new <<EOF
  <root>
    <add key="A" value="B" />
    <add key="C" value="D" />
    <add foo="E" bar="F" />
  </root>
EOF

get_pair xml_doc, "//*/@key", "../@value"
get_pair xml_doc, "//*/@foo", "../@bar"
```

produces:

```
"A" "B"
"C" "D"
"E" "F"
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Nokogiri is the fastest Ruby XML parser

See http://www.rubyinside.com/nokogiri-ruby-html-parser-and-xml-parser-1288.html

Was using it today and it's great.

For your example:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(your_xml)
doc.xpath("/root/add").map do |add|
  puts [add['key'], add['value']]
end
```

**Edit**: It unsurprisingly turns outthat the claim that Nokogiri is faster is not uncontroversial.

However, we have found it more stable than libxml in our production environmenty (libxml was occasionally crashing; just swapping in Nokogiri has solved the issue)

Comment: It's described as "slightly slower than libxml-ruby" in the http://tenderlovemaking.com/2008/10/30/nokogiri-is-released/ comments section.

Answer (score 1):

And if you will be parsing a decent amount of data in any area where performance matters, then you will need [libxml-ruby](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/).  REXML and Hpricot are good, but I recently had to make the switch on my own server for some parsing stuff because it was about 1200% faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest looking at Hpricot ... it is a very expressive HTML and XML parsing library, inspired by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

rexml, which comes with ruby will do what you want:

```
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML
xml = Document.new('<root><add key="A" value="B" /><add key="C" value="D" /><add foo="E" bar="F" /></root>')
xml.root.each_element_with_attribute('key'){|e| puts "#{e.attribute('key')} #{e.attribute('value')}"}
```