# Xpath query for Ruby objects

Tags: ruby, xpath

Is there any gem to query nested Ruby objects (specially Hash) with a XPath query like language? Once we are at it, even better if it provides also an equivalent for XQuery and XSLT

Just one requirement, I would not like something requiring a conversion to XML, YAML... or any other format that provides already the query language.

Comment: Do you have XML ? see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571663/ruby-xpath-to-find-attribute?rq=1), if it helps you.

Comment: if by dictionaries you are referring to a [Ruby Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html) then the `Hash` API is robust such purposes, otherwise you might need to serialize the Object to JSON, XML, YAML, then convert to an `Hash` to navigate

Comment: Serializing is not an option since a native ruby objects XPath can query through functions and objects that do not lend themselves to be serialized. "Must-be-serialized" is a very strong restriction for the cases I would use it.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [hpath-ruby](https://github.com/hpath/hpath-ruby) gem. You are able to use xpath feature addressing to search over hash/array embedded objects like follows:

```
Hpath.get record, "/price/*[(currency=USD|currency=EUR),value<10]"
```

where **record** is the hash-like object.